# How can I make h:inputText appear only after button clicked in JSF2.0?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

In jSF2.0 How can I make an `<h:inputText>` appear only after a specific button is clicked? I want the `<h:inputText>` be hidden, and only appear after I click a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you simply use CSS "display: none" attribute on inputText and, in button onclick attribute, to change this for "display: block". This is the more simple solution.